# How to properly filter existing class and create a new one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `UserRoles` class which assigns a role to the user. I need to create a sub-class which stores only those users whose `RoleId=2`. For that reason I created classes `SalesReps` and `SalesRepData`. Now, I want to add a method to `SalesReps` which returns a list of such filtered users. And later on I would like to use a class `SalesReps` as a property type in other classes (for example as a property `public SalesReps SalesRep {get; set;}`) and have access to the list of sales reps. I think I'm doing something wrong and it should be done differenty.
However, the main goal is to create a seperate, standalone `SalesReps` class of all sales reps which is retrieved from base `Users` class.

**User.cs**

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }

    }
```

**UserRole.cs**

```
    public class UserRole
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

**SalesRepData.cs**

```
    public class SalesRepData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
        public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }


        public SalesRepData(int id, string userName, string division, int isActive, UserRole userRole)
        {
            Id = id;
            UserName = userName;
            Division = division;
            IsActive = isActive;
            UserRole = userRole;
        }
    }
```

**SalesReps.cs**

```
    public class SalesReps
    {
        private static readonly List<SalesRepData> _salesRepData;
        private UserRole _userRole;

        private SalesReps(UserRole userRoles, List<SalesRepData> salesRepData)
        {
            _userRole = userRoles;
            _salesRepData = salesRepData;
        }

        public static List<SalesRepData> GetSalesRepList(int userRole=2, int isActive=1)
        {
            var allSalReps = _userRole.Find(f => f.UserRole.RoleId == userRole & f.User.IsActive == isActive);
            return _salesRepData.Add(allSalReps);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following (copy and paste the code below into https://dotnetfiddle.net/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    
    // User roles ...
    
    public class UserRole
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleDesc { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    // Divisions ...
    
    public class DivisionData
    {
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }
        public string DivisonName { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    // A user may have one (or more) roles and may belong to one (or more) divisions ...
    
    public class UserData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
        public HashSet<int> RoleIds { get; set; }
        public HashSet<int> DivisionIds { get; set; }

    }
    
    public class Users
    {
        
        // Key is user ID, value is userData ...

        private Dictionary<int, UserData> users;
        

        // Default constructor ...

        public Users() 
        {
            users = new Dictionary<int, UserData>();
        }
        

        // Add a user ...

        public void Add( UserData userData )
        {
            users.Add( userData.Id, userData ); 
        }
        

        // Returns a list of active sales reps ...

        public List<UserData> salesReps( int userRole = 2, int isActive = 1 )
        {
            
            List<UserData> salesRepsList;
            
            salesRepsList = new List<UserData>();
            
            foreach( KeyValuePair<int, UserData> user in users )
            {

                if ( user.Value.IsActive == isActive )
                {
                    
                    if ( user.Value.RoleIds.Contains( userRole ) )
                    {

                        salesRepsList.Add( user.Value );
                    
                    }
                        
                }
            
            }
            
            return salesRepsList;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {

        UserData user;
        
        Users users;
        
        List<UserData> salesReps;
            
            
        // Populate users ...

        users = new Users();
        
        user = new UserData 
               { 
                Id = 1,
                UserName = "User 1",
                IsActive = 1,
                RoleIds = new HashSet<int> { 2 },
                DivisionIds = new HashSet<int> { 1 }
                };
        
        users.Add( user );
        
        user = new UserData 
               { 
                Id = 2,
                UserName = "User 2",
                IsActive = 1,
                RoleIds = new HashSet<int> { 2 },
                DivisionIds = new HashSet<int> { 1 }
                };
        
        users.Add( user );
        
        
        user = new UserData 
               { 
                Id = 3,
                UserName = "User 3",
                IsActive = 1,
                RoleIds = new HashSet<int> { 1 },
                DivisionIds = new HashSet<int> { 1 }
                };
        
        users.Add( user );
        
        
        Console.WriteLine( "Active Sales Reps:" );
        
        salesReps = users.salesReps();
        
        foreach ( UserData u in salesReps ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"- Name: {u.UserName}" );
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort to write this example code. So If I understand correctly you use method to return list of active sales reps in `Users` class. Is there a chance to do the same in your `UserData` class ? Because I would like to store filtered users directly in a class. Not sure if inheritance would help out (`public class UserData : Users`)

Comment: Hi @mustafa00 - yes, you could use inheritance or use the list of active sales reps as input to a constructor of a new class.